# How to define the content of repeater inside composite through its interface?

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have a composite component with a `ui:repeat` and want to define the content of the `ui:repeat` through the interface of the composite.

Following code is working in MyFaces but looks more like a hack since variable name `varRepeat` must be known outside of composite and it only works if no other childrens are provided that should be rendered somewhere else.

**View**

*Define content of the `ui:repeat`*

```
<comp:myRepeater value="#{of:createIntegerArray(1,5)}">
    <h:outputText id="varComp" value="#{varRepeat}"/>
</comp:myRepeater>
```

**Composite myRepeater**

```
<composite:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Object"/>
<composite:implementation>
    <ui:repeat var="varRepeat" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <composite:insertChildren/>
    </ui:repeat>
</composite:implementation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the best you can get given that `var` attribute doesn't support EL. To make it clear to the enduser, document the name of `var` in `<cc:interface shortDescription>` and/or `<cc:attribute shortDescription>`.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.util.Collection" 
        shortDescription="A collection of items. Each item is exposed in EL under the variable name 'item'." />
<cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="item">
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </ui:repeat>
</cc:implementation>
```

Usage:

```
<my:repeat value="#{bean.list}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
</my:repeat>
```

---

The [OmniFaces showcase application](http://showcase.omnifaces.org) has also a similar composite for long: [`<os:listDocs>`](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/showcase/listdocs.xhtml):

```
<cc:implementation>
    <c:set var="docs" value="#{page.current.documentation[cc.attrs.paths]}" />
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty docs}">
        <h3>#{cc.attrs.header}</h3>
        <ul>
            <ui:repeat value="#{docs}" var="path">
                <li><a href="#{cc.attrs.url}"><code>#{cc.attrs.label}</code></a></li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
    </ui:fragment>
</cc:implementation>
```

[Usage](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/showcase.xhtml):

```
<os:listdocs header="VDL" paths="vdl" url="#{_vdlURL}#{path}.html" label="#{fn:replace(path,'/', ':')}" />
<os:listdocs header="API" paths="api" url="#{_apiURL}#{path}.html" label="#{fn:replace(path,'/', '.')}" /> 
<os:listdocs header="Source code" paths="api" url="#{_srcURL}#{path}.java" label="#{fn:replace(path,'/', '.')}" />
```

As a design hint, if you use a sensible attribute name for the collection, the `var` may become more self-documenting. E.g. ask for `items` as value and provide a `var="item"`.

```
<my:repeat items="#{[1,2,3,4,5]}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
</my:repeat>
```

Comment: I see. Maybe one day we can pass a composite interface as an argument to a composite (like OOP programming). The naming was just to make the `var` attribute clear. Is `#{[1,2,3,4,5]}`pseudocode or a new feature? Fails in myfaces.