# Is it possible to pass a reusable template/fragment to a composite component in JSF?

Tags: jsf, facelets

Is it possible to pass some sort of parametrized fragment/template to be reused inside a composite component?

```
<my:list value="#{someBean.ratios}" var="ratio">
    <???>
        <h:outputText value="#{ratio}">
            <f:convertNumber type="percent" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" />
        </h:outputText>
    </???>
</my:list>
```

with the following `my:list` component:

```
<ui:component>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" />
        <cc:attribute name="var" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <ul>
            <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="item">
                <li>
                    <???insert body/fragment/template???>
                        <ui:param name="#{cc.attrs.var}" value="#{item}" />
                    </???insert body/fragment/template???>
                </li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

**UPDATE** I have also tried something like that but it does not work:

```
<my:list value="#{someBean.ratios}">
    <f:convertNumber type="percent" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" for="output" />
</my:list>
```

with component defined as:

```
<ui:component>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <ul>
            <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="item">
                <li>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item}" id="output" />
                </li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302211

Comment: Thanks, that helped. In the end, I managed to make my second method work (see my update), my real world usecase was a bit more complex (I am displaying tuples and need the template twice) and the examples in the [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/) are not correct (when using cc:valueHolder, multiple targets must be separated by spaces, not by commas).

Comment: You're right the example is wrong, it does however say on the same page "If present, this must be a space (not tab) separated list of client ids"